# Can Firebase 100% replace Appsflyers for mobile attribution?

Tags: analytics

Since the last update with Firebase, we are now thinking about leaving Appsflyer and going with Firebase 100% for our mobile tracking. Our only challenge is tracking FB ad installs. Suggestions, comments?